# WCF duplex issues with multiple clients in different threads

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, duplex

I set up a WCF duplex service (one-way messages) and multiple clients in the same process (for testing) using CustomBinding over TCP.

It all works fine as long as only one client gets called back. However it fails for multiple clients. In the latter case one client works, others can send their request but do not get the response. The server can send all responses without problems.
WCF tracing shows an EndpointNotFoundException on the client side:

```
There was no channel that could accept the message with action
'http://tempuri.org/IMyService/Response'.
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ThrowAndCatch(Exception e, Message message)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.ProcessItem(TInnerItem item)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.HandleReceiveResult(IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DatagramChannelDemuxer`2.OnReceiveCompleteStatic(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.InputChannel.HelpReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.Dispatch()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.DispatchItems()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DuplexSessionOneWayChannelListener.ChannelReceiver.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceive(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously, Exception exception)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.ReceiveAsyncResult.OnReceiveComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

At the time of the exception I am sure that all client channels are still open since they close only after they receive the response.
It looks like the client receives the message but cannot send it to the client instance.

Here my full example (WCF config by code):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WcfDuplex
{
  [TestClass]
  public class WcfDuplexTest
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void WcfDuplexTest1()
    {
      const int NumParallelRequests = 2;
      const int NumMessagesPerThread = 1;
      using (var host = MyServer.CreateServer(TestContext))
      {
        Action clientAction = () =>
          {
            using (var client = MyClient.CreateProxy(TestContext))
            {
              using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client))
              {
                var callback = MyClient.GetCallbackHandler(client);
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo = client.LocalAddress;
                for (int i = 1; i <= NumMessagesPerThread; i++)
                {
                  string message = String.Format("Message {0} from tread {1}", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                  client.Request(message);
                  bool success = callback.MessageArrived.WaitOne(5000);
                  Assert.IsTrue(success, "Timeout while waiting for: " + message);
                  Assert.IsTrue(callback.Message.EndsWith(message));
                }
              }
              client.Close();
            }
          };
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumParallelRequests; i++)
          tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(clientAction));
        foreach (var task in tasks)
          task.Wait(10000);
      }
    }

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }

  [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyCallback))]
  interface IMyService
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Request(string message);
  }

  [ServiceContract()]
  interface IMyCallback
  {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Response(string message);
  }

  interface IMyServiceChannel : IMyService, IClientChannel
  { }

  [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
  class MyService : IMyService
  {
    public void Request(string message)
    {
      var context = OperationContext.Current.Host.Extensions.Find<TestContextExtension>().TestContext;
      var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallback>();
      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.To = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo.Uri;
      context.WriteLine("Server received message: {0}. Reply to {1}", message, OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.To);
      string responseMessage = "From server thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": " + message;
      callback.Response(responseMessage);
      context.WriteLine("Server sent response: " + responseMessage);
    }
  }

  class MyCallbackHandler : IMyCallback, IExtension<IContextChannel>
  {

    private readonly TestContext Context;
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public AutoResetEvent MessageArrived { get; private set; }

    public MyCallbackHandler(TestContext context)
    {
      Context = context;
      MessageArrived = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    }

    public void Response(string message)
    {
      Message = message;
      Context.WriteLine("Client received message: " + message + " on " + OperationContext.Current.Channel.LocalAddress +
        " in thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      MessageArrived.Set();
    }

    public void Attach(IContextChannel owner) { }
    public void Detach(IContextChannel owner) { }
  }

  class MyServer
  {
    public const string Url = "net.tcp://localhost:8731/MyService/";

    public static ServiceHost CreateServer(TestContext context)
    {
      var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
      host.Extensions.Add(new TestContextExtension { TestContext = context });
      host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), MyClient.GetBinding(), new Uri(MyServer.Url));
      host.Open();
      return host;
    }
  }

  class TestContextExtension : IExtension<ServiceHostBase>
  {
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
    public void Attach(ServiceHostBase owner) { }
    public void Detach(ServiceHostBase owner) { }
  }

  class MyClient
  {
    public static MyCallbackHandler GetCallbackHandler(IMyServiceChannel channel)
    {
      var callback = channel.Extensions.Find<MyCallbackHandler>();
      return callback;
    }

    public static IMyServiceChannel CreateProxy(TestContext testContext)
    {
      var callback = new MyCallbackHandler(testContext);
      var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callback);
      var binding = GetBinding();
      int port = 8732;// +Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      binding.Elements.Find<CompositeDuplexBindingElement>().ClientBaseAddress = new Uri(String.Format("net.tcp://localhost:{0}/Client/", port));
      binding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
      var clientFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyServiceChannel>(instanceContext, binding);
      var client = clientFactory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(MyServer.Url));
      client.Extensions.Add(callback);
      return client;
    }

    public static CustomBinding GetBinding()
    {
      var binding = new CustomBinding(
        new CompositeDuplexBindingElement(),
        new OneWayBindingElement(),
        new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
        //new ReliableSessionBindingElement(),
        new TcpTransportBindingElement());
      return binding;
    }
  }
}
```

I used the following articles as help: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx), [here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/04/when-you-think-things-are-not-possible-wcf-duplex-callbacks-through-nats-and-firewalls---safe-and-secure.html), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the binding. 
What works is:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding(
  new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
  new ReliableSessionBindingElement(),
  new TcpTransportBindingElement());
```

The CompositeDuplexBindingElement and OneWayBindingElement cause the trouble. They are not needed for TCP type channels.

What also works are:

```
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
```

or

```
var binding = new WSDualHttpBinding(WSDualHttpSecurityMode.None);
binding.ClientBaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8732/Client/");
```